# Build failed while deploying github pages with Hugo and Travis

Tags: travis-ci, hugo

I am using Travis CI to deploy github pages using latest Hugo version

> v0.59.1

however the build fails with the following error.

```
1.36s$ curl -LO https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/download/v0.59.1/hugo_0.59.1_Linux-64bit.deb install.2
1.29s$ sudo dpkg -i hugo_0.55.4_Linux-64bit.deb
0.08s$ hugo
Building sites … ERROR 2019/11/11 10:54:14 error: failed to transform 
resource: TOCSS: failed to transform "style.scss" (text/x-sass): this 
feature is not available in your current Hugo version
Total in 27 ms
Error: Error building site: logged 1 error(s)
The command "hugo" exited with 255.
```

Below is My .travis.yml

```
---
install:
- wget -O /tmp/hugo.deb 
https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/download/v0.59.1/hugo_0.59.1_Linux-64bit.deb
- sudo dpkg -i /tmp/hugo.deb

 script:
  - hugo

 deploy:
   - provider: script
     script: bash deploy.sh
     skip_cleanup: true
     on:
       branch: source
```

Any suggestions as to how to address this issue? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing similar issue, It worked for me after replacing  `hugo_extended_0.59.1_Linux-64bit.deb` instead of `hugo_0.59.1_Linux-64bit.deb`